# log normal statistics

Tags: statistics

I've got a problem here. Could you help me, please?

> "The data shown that mean value for the toxicity is $750$ mg. The mode for the distribution is $250$ mg of material. Assume the data fit a log-normal curve and plot the graph."

My question is, how to get $\mu (z)$ and SD?

Comment: what is $\mu(z)$ in terms of the underlying distribution? How does the **mode** of distribution influence mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

A random variable $\ T\ $ is [log-normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) if $\ \ln\left(T\right)\ $ is normally distributed.  If the mean and variance of $\ \ln\left(T\right)\ $ are $\ \mu\ $ and $\ \sigma^2\ $ respectively, then the mean and mode of $\ T\ $ are $\ e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\ $ $\\(=750$ mg., in your case) and $\ e^{\mu-\sigma^2}\ $ ($=250$ mg. in your case). The equations $\ e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\ =750\ $ and $\ e^{\mu-\sigma^2}=250\ $ enable you to determine the values of $\ \mu\ $ and $\ \sigma^2\ $, and hence plot the graph of either the cumulative distribution function of $\ T\ $ or its density function.

If you need the standard deviation of $\ T\ $, its value as a function of $\ \mu\ $ and $\ \sigma\ $ is $\ \sqrt{e^{2\mu+\sigma^2}\left(e^{\sigma^2}-1\right)}\ $.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a bunch!